# How to store the message mqtt-paho golang received?

Tags: go, mqtt, paho

To be more specific, I want to store the last 20 messages in an array for later use.

I am working on the example code [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/golang/index.php).

I was going to build a global variable and store **MSG. Payload()** in it. But I found that the main function is only executed once in the whole process of running the program. Do I need to write all my logic in **MQTT.MessageHandler**?

I'm really confused, thanks for your help.

Comment: [The examples](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/tree/master/cmd) show you how to [wait for a signal](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/cmd/docker/subscriber/main.go#L153) before exiting. Incoming messages will trigger a call to your callback; how you handle these is up to you (update a global slice, push messages to a channel etc). It will be easier to assist you if you make an attempt at this and show us your code along with a description of what is not working.

Comment: I have applied the exit signal, and it works very well. From your example, my understanding is: the main function is executed only once and does not process messages; If I need to do anything with the message, I have to write some new handlers. Is my understanding correct? Here is my [code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9KdSzHCzfB/).

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code (links may break in the future). As per [the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) "Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete" (so yes, `main` is only executed once). When a message arrives the handler will be called; this happens in a goroutine - if you are new to go working through [the tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1) might help.